# UseWindowsService OS Power Event Handler

Tags: .net, windows-services

I need my windows service to react gracefully when the OS goes on Stand by or when there is a low power situation.  Old school, I'd tie into the OnPowerEvents event but I don't see how to do that in the .NET Framework 7 definition.  Anyone have a working example of how to subscribe to system events from a windows service that hosts an app service?

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
```

I have not found this in the Host object, IServiceCollection or the AddHostedService definitions.